# Setting IndexedDB Storage Location in Electron

Tags: webpack, electron, indexeddb, localforage

I've got an electron-webpack app that I'd like to persist data locally with. I'm trying to use localForage/IndexedDB as my backing store, but I'm running into some issues with my development cycle. In particular, I can't seem to load data previously persisted once I fully quit the electron app and restart it. However, reloading the app via a Hot Module Reload works.

I did some digging and it looks like IndexedDB creates a directory with a host:port pair every time the app is started:

```
(env) vishalkuo@Vishal's Macbook Pro client $ ll ~/Library/Application\ Support/Electron/IndexedDB/
total 0
8599832812 0 drwx------   7 vishalkuo  staff   224B  7 Jan 19:45 http_localhost_60612.indexeddb.leveldb
8599835990 0 drwx------   8 vishalkuo  staff   256B  7 Jan 22:33 http_localhost_58090.indexeddb.leveldb
8599836127 0 drwx------   7 vishalkuo  staff   224B  7 Jan 22:33 http_localhost_58692.indexeddb.leveldb
8599832810 0 drwx------   6 vishalkuo  staff   192B  7 Jan 22:34 .
8599836209 0 drwx------   7 vishalkuo  staff   224B  7 Jan 22:34 http_localhost_58788.indexeddb.leveldb
```

and the ports seem to coincide with the webpack-dev-server being run.

I'm wondering if IndexedDB or localForage have any options to circumvent this naming strategy in favour of a user provided one or if I should look for other storage strategies

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem today and I found this post. Maybe this will be useful for somebody in future. In main process just before `app.on("ready", createWindow);` I added: `app.setPath("userData", "DB_NEW_LOCATION");`.

Dont forget to add `"extraFiles": ["DB_NEW_LOCATION"/**/*"]` in your package.json if u want persist data after build.